# Fastest way to transfer data between 2 attached EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rsync, file-transfer, data-transfer

I'm trying to copy data between 2 ebs volumes on an EC2 instance the fastest way possible while being safe with the data. I cannot do a block level copy as I'm going from a bigger sized volume to a smaller sized volume. I'm essentially running a script that will "shrink" these ebs volumes (copying data from the original volume to a smaller volume).

I have sorted through many articles and tried things like cp -a and rclone -a as I need to retain the permissions and metadata on the volumes (ruling out rclone, as rclone doesn't retain permissions). I have landed on msrsync because of this as I had believed it to be the fastest option.

I have also tried to shrink the partition of the larger volume to the size of the smaller volume and do a block level copy with dd and pv, but that turned out to be dangerous. I would get a corrupted drive and see some weird glitches most of the time, however it is very fast. 200+ m/s.

Currently with msrsync, copying as little as 40 gigs is taking over an hour. I will list the variables I'm working with.

- aws ec2 m5.8xlarge running ami `amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220606.1-x86_64-gp2` (thinking that larger volumes have higher throughput, and m5's are ebs optimized however that is turning out to not help as much as I thought).
- ebs gp3 with 10,000 iops and 750 throughput on both drives. any less and it takes many hours.
- msrsync copy command (documentation - https://github.com/jbd/msrsync) with the following flags: `sudo ./msrsync -p16 -P --rsync "-avAXEWSlHh --info=progress2" /mnt/datacopy$j/ /mnt/newdatacopy$j`. I opted to use 16 threads when possible as the m5.8xlarge has many cores.
- test files are from https://fastest.fish/test-files. I WAS generating my test files with `dd` and `fallocate`, but for some reason they would not show up as usage on the volumes (after ensuring permissions were normal). I will try multiple and a single file, and msrsync helps the multiple files but can't help the single file much.

`msrsync` is showing

```
[1/6 entries] [16.0 K/78.1 G transferred] [235 entries/s] [3.7 M/s bw] [monq 8] [jq 1]


[2/6 entries] [9.1 G/78.1 G transferred] [0 entries/s] [5.5 M/s bw] [monq 1] [jq 1]
[3/6 entries] [19.1 G/78.1 G transferred] [0 entries/s] [10.5 M/s bw] [monq 0] [jq 1]
[4/6 entries] [29.1 G/78.1 G transferred] [0 entries/s] [15.8 M/s bw] [monq 1] [jq 1]
[5/6 entries] [39.1 G/78.1 G transferred] [0 entries/s] [21.2 M/s bw] [monq 1] [jq 1]
```

currently with 5 10GB test files, and a 500GB total ebs volume.

after looking at iotop and htop, I'm not sure where I'm bottlenecking. Are ebs volumes just slow even with the throughput and iops I'm using? Any information or tips would be extremely appreciated.

EDIT: adjusted phrasing regarding permissions

Comment: "but I need to retain the permissions and metadata on the volumes.". `cp -a` and `rsync -a` both do this. Hadn't heard of `msrsync` but it appears to be optimized for transfer over a network.

Comment: @jordanm i'll adjust my phrasing, I meant to say "because I need to retain permissions I've tried cp -a and rsync -a". My needing to retain the permissions makes it so that I cannot use something like rclone.

Comment: That performance does seem incredibly low. Are you recreating your source volume from a snapshot? If yes, you are paying the cost of populating the volume blocks from S3 before you are able to copy them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html

Comment: @kdgregory that is hugely helpful. That would explain my frustration and confusion as I have seen speeds of 200m/s+ when I was doing some testing without snapshots involved, but running everything in sequence it plummets.

Comment: using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/enable-fast-snapshot-restores.html in my script did the trick! thank you so much @kdgregory

Comment: Beware that you're billed per-hour for fast restore. Remember to disable when you're done with your tests, or you might end up with a nasty surprise at the end of the month: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-fast-snapshot-restore.html#fsr-pricing

Comment: @kdgregory odd, i'm still experiencing a lot of latency (5 m/s total read/write) after the volume is created from fast snapshot restore enabled snapshot. For some reason, if i stop the instance, start it and start the copy again the next day i get what I believe to be the full i/o. around 150 m/s.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your use-case, but if you are trying to copy data from EBS volume created from a snap to a smaller empty EBS volume and see low read performance from the source volume (with or without FSR), then I'd suggest a simple check. Try to read the entire content of the source volume via dd with large block size first. m5.8xl is capable of 850MB/s and your volume is provisioned to deliver 750MB/s, but until warm-up is done you should see ~250MB/s read throughput, so it will take time. Then try msrsync to see if you get more consistent performance.

Comment: I think the fastest way will be block-level copy operation between two EBS volumes. Perhaps you may change your source volume, shrink FS there and copy N sectors…

AFAIK you cannot offload EBS copy, so you have to do that via EC2 and if you want to speed things up you may select EC2 type with enough EBS throughput and potentially use io2 for the source volume (io2 will have faster warm-up time comparing to gp3 but has higher cost).

Comment: @DmitryKrivenok thanks Dmitry, you're exactly right about the warm-up. I just thought it was odd that even after the state of fast restore being enabled, it was still not fully warmed up after the new volume was restored with the snapshot. You're also correct about block-level being the fastest way, but for my use case it ended up making sense to not make a snapshot at all, and just copy the data from the original volume onto a fully initialized smaller volume via msrsync.

Comment: Are your EBS volumes in different regions? If so, the inter-region transfer may be the bottleneck. A workaround would be to have each volume sync with S3 (which would be up to 100 Gbps bandwidth) and use a tool like [Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane) to sync the buckets.